# Eclipse control statement curly braces indented incorrectly

Tags: c++, eclipse, coding-style, eclipse-cdt, gnu

I'm trying to use a GNU-based coding style in Eclipse Galileo for C++. By default, conditional statements look like this:

```
if (true)
  {
    return;
  }
```

The curly braces are being indented, when they should line up under the if statement and the following line shouldn't be double-indented. This is what I want:

```
if (true)
{
  return;
}
```

I can find all of the settings to control where the curly braces appear for control statements, but I can't find the command to stop indenting the curly braces. Can someone give me a recommendation?

Comment: The GNU style _does_ indent the curly braces.  (That's a good reason not to use it.)

Comment: True. The FOSS project I'm working on uses an adapted GNU style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting your searching for is under `Edit...`->`Braces`->`Blocks`. Setting it to `Next Line` is what you want.

You have to copy the build-in GNU coding style to a new profile before you can edit the coding style.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that option. Thanks!